# List<Class> variable returns null even when assigned a value

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a java code file,

```
public class PropertyRequestService {

static String result;
PropertiesList localProperty = new PropertiesList();
List<PropertiesList> Properties;


public List<PropertiesList> getAllPropertiesStuff() {
    JSONArray json = null;
    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "Given URL");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs
                .add(Passing parameter));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);

        // HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // if (entity != null) {

        /*
         * result = EntityUtils.toString(entity); Log.i("RESPONSE=",
         * result);
         */
        // List<PropertiesList> tst=(List<PropertiesList>)response;

        ArrayList<String> jsonstring = getJSONString(response);

        System.out.println("jsonString : " + jsonstring);
        json = new JSONArray(jsonstring);       

        localProperty.angle=30;
            localProperty.PropertyID =Integer.parseInt(json.getString(0));
            localProperty.Latitude =Double.parseDouble(json.getString(2));
            localProperty.Longitude = Double.parseDouble(json.getString(3));
            localProperty.PropertyPrice = Integer.parseInt(json.getString(4));
            localProperty.PropertyAddress = json.getString(1);
            localProperty.listfrom=0;

            Properties.add(localProperty);


    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Properties;
}

public ArrayList<String> getJSONString(HttpResponse response) {

    try {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream((result.replace("&",
                " ")).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = builder.parse(stream);

        NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("PropertyID");
        NodeList n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Address");
        NodeList n3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Lat");
        NodeList n4 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Lng");
        NodeList n5 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Price");
        Node nn1 = n1.item(0);
        Node nn2 = n2.item(0);
        Node nn3 = n3.item(0);
        Node nn4 = n4.item(0);
        Node nn5 = n5.item(0);
        String str1 = nn1.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        String str2 = nn2.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        String str3 = nn3.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        String str4 = nn4.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        String str5 = nn5.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

        ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
        nodes.add(str1);
        nodes.add(str2);
        nodes.add(str3);
        nodes.add(str4);
        nodes.add(str5);

        System.out.println("Node value : " + nodes);
        return nodes;
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

and PropertiesList class,

```
public class PropertiesList {

 public int angle;
 public int PropertyID;
 public int PropertyPrice;
 public String PropertyAddress;
 public Double Latitude;
 public Double Longitude;
 public static int listfrom;
}
```

and from the activity class I call like this,

```
   PropertyRequestService properties=new PropertyRequestService();
    propertyRSList=  properties.getAllPropertiesStuff();
```

The problem is that, near the line "Properties.add(localProperty);", I did observe that Properties variable is null and Exception is caught. 
  There is no syntax error or logical error according to me. Did I miss anything or any wrong assignment?

This is my logcat,

```
05-22 17:51:46.192: W/dalvikvm(3317): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.BuildersUpdate/com.BuildersUpdate.PropertySearchTypes.CameraSearch}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at com.BuildersUpdate.PropertySearchTypes.PropertyRequestService.getAllPropertiesStuff(PropertyRequestService.java:90)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at com.BuildersUpdate.PropertySearchTypes.CameraSearch.onCreate(CameraSearch.java:200)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-22 17:51:46.684: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Please suggest me and correct me!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where do you expect `Properties` to be set to a non-null value? I can't see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet you need to add this kind of thing as an answer, it's a easy reputation :)

Comment: @MarkoLazić Jon Skeet has 567,047 reputations! He don't need easy reputations! **Edit:** 567,062 now.

Comment: @johnchen902 That was just a joke :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate `Properties` before you access it. Use:

```
List<PropertiesList> Properties = new ArrayList<>();
```

instead of:

```
List<PropertiesList> Properties;
```

BTW, according to java naming conventions, variables should start with lower case letter, so it is better to use `properties` instead.

Comment: Yes instantiated it but still returns the same null value. Properties is shown as null!! :-(

Comment: Do it before the method, not inside. Or use: Properties = new ArrayList<>(); inside the method. Otherwise you hide the global `Properties` field.

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized the `List<Properties> Properties`. You have just created a reference to it.

```
List<Properties> Properties = new ArrayList<Properties>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have just defined a reference **Properties** which will point to object of type ArrayList. You also need to create the actual object using the **new()** operator.

```
List<PropertiesList> Properties = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can add your data in it.

```
Properties.add(localProperty);
```

**Take care of your namings**. Variable,functions must be in **camel case** i.e starts with a small letter and subsequent words start with capital letter. Words starting with caps are generally names of classes.